# jmeter kafka SASL cant send message

Tags: apache-kafka, jmeter

i am learning how to send msg to kafka.
Created broker at cloudkarafka and trying send simple message from jsr223, but got error
Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator
Error connecting to node dory.srvs.cloudkafka.com:9094 (id: -1 rack: null)
What i am doing wrong? help please!

[image]

```
    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config" , "C:/!work/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/kafka-jaas.conf");
//System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config" , "kafka-jaas.conf");
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
import java.util.Properties;
    Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "dory.srvs.cloudkafka.com:9094");
       properties.put("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
       properties.put("sasl.mechanism", "PLAINTEXT");                     
       properties.put("acks", "1");
       properties.put("retries", 1);
       properties.put("batch.size", 16384);
       properties.put("linger.ms", 0);
       properties.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
       properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
       properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");        
       properties.put("compression.type", "none");
       properties.put("send.buffer.bytes", 131072);
       properties.put("receive.buffer.bytes", 32768);      
       properties.put("sasl.kerberos.service.name", "kafka");
       properties.put("ssl.keystore.type", "JKS");
       properties.put("ssl.truststore.type", "JKS");
       Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
       producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("lzejnhew-qwe", "{\n\t\"messageId\":{{SEQUENCE(\"messageId\", 1, 1)}},\n\t\"messageBody\":\"{{RANDOM_ALPHA_NUMERIC(\"abcedefghijklmnopqrwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRWXYZ\", 100)}}\",\n\t\"messageCategory\":\"{{RANDOM_STRING(\"Finance\", \"Insurance\", \"Healthcare\", \"Shares\")}}\",\n\t\"messageStatus\":\"{{RANDOM_STRING(\"Accepted\",\"Pending\",\"Processing\",\"Rejected\")}}\",\n\t\"messageTime\":{{TIMESTAMP()}}\n}"));
        producer.close();
```

Kafka-jaas.conf:

```
KafkaClient {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
serviceName="lzejnhew-qwe"
username="lzejnhew"
password="***";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think questions like this should go to [CloudKafka support](https://www.cloudkarafka.com/support.html)

Also your question doesn't provide enough level of details so we cannot guess the nature of your problem, going forward consider adding the relevant part of [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file showing the full [stacktrace](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-read-and-understand-a-java-stacktrace) preferably with [JMeter debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the JMeter components and/or 3rd-party libraries you're using.

So far I can only suggest trying to use [KafkaExample.java](https://github.com/CloudKarafka/java-kafka-example/blob/main/src/main/java/KafkaExample.java) demo code which is mentioned in the [CloudKafka documentation](https://www.cloudkarafka.com/docs/java.html) as a basis, it has slightly different login configuration from yours, it might be sufficient to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have to install local kafka, i still dont understand what is wrong in my first code cloud kafka, but can send msg to local kafka.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

import java.util.Properties;


        String bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

        // create the producer
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);

        log.info("kafka IP   " + properties.getProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG));


        // create producer record
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test", "Hello from jmeter");


        // send data
        producer.send(record);
        producer.flush();
        producer.close();
```